# How can I get the program to display only the longest word not each word in the string?

Tags: python, function

```
def find_longest_word(string):
    d = []
    a = string.split()  
    for x in a:
        b = (x.count("") - 1)
        d.append(b)
        f = max(d)
        print (x, f)

find_longest_word("hello my name is k")
```

The program will print each word with the length of the longest beside each, however I only want it to print the longest word. Please help.

Comment: Use `len` to get the length of a string in Python, and if you don't want it to print a bunch of a words, put the `print` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_longest_word(string):
    a = string.split()  
    f = -1
    longest = None
    for x in a:
        if len(x) > f:
            f = len(x)
            longest = x
    print (longest, f)

>>> find_longest_word("hello my name is k")
('hello', 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short and simple function to find the longest word in a sentence:

```
def find_longest_word(s):
    return max([(len(w), w) for w in s.split(" ")])[1]
```

Example:

```
find_longest_word("This is an incredibly long sentence!")
>>> incredibly
```

**Explanation**:
This creates a list of tuples with the list comprehension and the `s.split(" ")`, and then stores the length of the word and the word itself in the tuple. The max function is then called on the list of tuples, and it retrieves the tuple with the longest length of word (i.e., the zeroth tuple parameter), and then it simply returns the word (i.e., the first tuple parameter) with the `...)[1]`.

**Note**: If you would like to return the length of the word, and the word itself, you can simply modify the function to be: `return max([(len(w), w) for w in s.split(" ")])`. This removes the indexing into the tuple and returns the full tuple.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
def longest(s):
    return sorted(s.split(), key=len, reverse=True)[0]

print longest("this is a string")
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.count("")` returns the number of times `""` shows up in the string.  Let's say the string is "mystring".  `"m"` is not `""`, `"y"` is not `""`, `"s"` is not `""`, etc.  The total count: 0.  To get the length of a string, use `len(x)`.  Also, you make `f` equal the highest number in `d`, not `b`.  Here is a modified version:

```
def find_longest_word(string):
    a = string.split()
    longest = max(((word, len(word)) for word in a), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print longest
```

Test:

```
find_longest_word("This is my sentence that has a longest word.")
```

Output:

```
('sentence', 8)
```

If you want it to print it like `sentence: 8`, use `print '{}: {}'.format(longest)`